# How do you import jsonschema?

Tags: python, python-import

I have this very simple code that validates a Json schema:

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {"type" : "object","properties" : {"command":{"type" : "string"}},"required": ["command"]}
request= {"command":12} 

try:
    jsonschema.validate(request, schema)
except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
    print e.message
except jsonschema.SchemaError as e:
    print e
```

and I'm getting;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./json_validator.py", line 8, in <module>
    except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
NameError: name 'jsonschema' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `import jsonschema`, since you are using `jsonschema.validate` and `jsonschema.ValidationError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you import like

```
from jsonschema import validate
```

`validate` from the module `jsonschema` will be available in your current module. You have to use it as `validate` not as `jsonschema.validate`.

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {"type" : "object","properties" : {"command":{"type" : "string"}},"required": ["command"]}
request= {"command":12} 

try:
    validate(request, schema)
except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
    print e.message
except jsonschema.SchemaError as e:
    print e
```

Your code is also missing the imports for the Exceptions:

```
from jsonschema import validate, ValidationError, SchemaError
```

Comment: Given they've explicitly referenced the module everywhere, seems like a better fix would be to just do `import jsonschema`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman True, but I just wanted to explain the problem.